# Understanding the ECG waveform with respect to Lead Positions

Tags: neuroscience, cardiology, electrocardiography, heart-output

I am really confused about the Representation of potential in an ECG graph.

**First i will ask what is on the vertical axis?** (I guess it is electrical potential in millivolts)
But again it changes for various positions and the graph takes a different shape. These are called **Lead positions** ( correct me if i am wrong )
I don't understand why **the waveform changes for different Lead positions**. ***Basically I do not understand how the ECG machine works in relation to what happens in the heart*** ( i.e. the action potentials from SA nodes and so on...) [image]

This diagram shows what I meant.
**How am I supposed to interpret the data** if it is different depending on direction.

I will be grateful if someone can also provide some information on the cardinal directions in these cases.

Thanks!